# How do i add Object to Firebase RTDB

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi so i have a JSON file on RTDB and would like to add a new entry. I tried using retool but it keeps overwriting the DB.

Let's say i have something like this

```
"items" : [{"item" : "value"},{"item" : "value"}]
```

In the Firebase console the structure is as such where the first object has an **Index of 0** and for other object it increases, hierarchical.

I want to add new object so that the newest object added gets **Index 0**.

How do i accomplish that without using a text editor to update the JSON then re-upload ?

Answer (score 1):

When you store an array like yours in Firebase Realtime Database, it ends up being stored as:

```
"items": {
  "0": { "item": "value" },
  "1": { "item": "value" }
}
```

If you want to add a new item in index 0, you will have to:

1. Read the existing items into your application.
2. Move current item 0 and 1 to indexes 1 and 2.
3. Add the new item at index 0.

This is not very difficult to do in code, but does mean that:

- You need to read all existing items, which will become prohibitive as the list grows.
- You need to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) to read-then-update the array, which limits concurrency (it won't scale to many users) and means the operation cannot be performed while offline.

For these reasons Firebase recommends not using arrays for list-structures, but instead using its built in [`push()` operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data) to append items to a list. The `push()` operation generates unique keys that prevent the above problems.

So with `push()` the newest item is always at the end of the list, meaning you can read it from there instead of index 0, or use a query with `limitToLast()` to get the most recent item(s).

I recommend also reading:

- [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

Comment: So if i have a JSON file and would like the same result, what should i do ?

Comment: If you want to be able to manipulate the arrays in that data in Firebase after importing it, I'd recommend converting them to use `push()` keys during the import process.

Comment: I don't understand . I do not have that option when using the web console. Are you speaking of the command line ? what would that code look like ?

Comment: No, that'd require that you write code to read your JSON file and call the Firebase API to insert it into the database. If you import an array with the console, it'll show up as I showed in my JSON snippet and with all problems I identified.

Comment: So, i would have to individually push all "/refs" to the db ?

Comment: how would i write such code ? Please